# iPhone can't play any music

Tags: iphone

Hi all. I used to be able to play music with my iPhone but now I can't.

I'm not sure what causes this problem, and I'm wondering if this is a hardware problem.

I performed a clean factory restore, made sure the volume is maxed, but there's no sound at all. I've installed an alternate music player but there's still no sound (even though volume is maxed).

Does anyone know if there's anything else I can do to reset the phone besides the factory restore option in iTunes?

Comment: Q: does the music player appear to be playing music but you hear no sound? Or does the music player just not even play any files on the device? What about a streaming audio player like Rdio or TuneIn?

Comment: Follow up Q: there's no sound with headphones and without headphones?

Comment: @IanC. The files are there, the lyrics and album art are showing, the "duration bar" is moving. It's playing as usual like before, except that now there's no sound. I've downloaded Rdio and tried playing some songs, but there's no sound. It's the same with tunein: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1iPn.png (shows "no volume available" regardless of how I toggle the volume button at the bottom left hand side)

Comment: @IanC. sry I don't understand your second question.. but I can receive phone calls (and talk and hear) fine.

Comment: I'm trying to deduce if there's something keeping your phone stuck in headphone mode. But your answers are good. They've got me thinking your phone is stuck in "line out" mode. Have you recently put the phone in a dock? Perhaps one that lets you play the audio out over larger speakers?

Comment: @IanC. I don't have a speaker. By "in a dock" do you mean plugging an earpiece into it? I've not recently used my earpiece. But after trying, the sound is coming out from the earpiece, but once I unplug the earpiece, the sound is gone. http://i.stack.imgur.com/EPjGu.png (earpiece plugged in). http://i.stack.imgur.com/UiDNo.png (not plugged in, the volume bar's not even showing)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answering my questions.

So with no headphones plugged in you get no sound through the built-in speakers on your iPhone.

Based on the screen shots you posted it looks like your phone thinks it's connected to a dock connection. That's jives with your "sound in headphones, no sound from internal speakers" answers to my questions.

It sounds very much like your dock connection at the bottom of the phone is not functioning correctly. It may just have some debris in it that's shorting out a few pins and making your iPhone think it's connected to a dock with a line-out on it, or it may be completely broken.

Try cleaning out the dock connection jack on the bottom of the phone. You can blow in it with a dry air source, compressed air in a can is best, to see if you can dislodge any debris from it. You can also try plugging your dock connector in and out a few times to see if that clears it up.

If that doesn't work your best bet is to take it an Apple Repair Depot and have them look at it. The dock connection is made up of a lot of small terminal points and it's not hard to mess them up if you force a connector in the wrong way or smush some debris in there when plugging it in to charge.

Comment: By the dock connection jack, do you mean the portion of the iphone which the usb (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Apple_Dock_Connector.jpg/220px-Apple_Dock_Connector.jpg) gets inserted into?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm referring to. It's on the bottom of your phone, centered between the two internal speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Press the sleep/wake button and the home button at the same time for 10 seconds to reset the music device.